# My code is generating an output "NaN". Why?

Tags: c++

I know that this error usually occurs when *some value is divided by 0.*
But in my case:

```
c[0]=((a[1]*b[2])-(a[2]*b[1]));
c[1]=((a[2]*b[0])-(a[0]*b[2]));
c[2]=((a[0]*b[1])-(a[1]*b[0]));
cout<<c[0]<<c[1]<<c[2];
```

This piece of code sometimes generate **NaN** as output

Comment: What are the types, and the input values when this happens? Add code to detect the `nan` and break, use a debugger to inspect the incoming values. Sometimes it's just "garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: Debugging is the first thing you do. So, done with that

Comment: @TusharChandra: Please don't take downvotes personally. For what it's worth, I don't see anything wrong with this question; perhaps though you could shorten it to two statements, and tidy up the title a bit. It's hard to formulate a worked example for such things, and the answer is concrete, assuming IEEE754.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am new to stackoverflow, so learning how to post question. I am sure you were also an amateur when you started. So, instead of down voting or putting the question on hold. Please try to help.

Comment: Being new doesn't excuse you from the quality requirements. It has nothing to do with the topic you are asking about (in fact it's quite interesting). Improve your post and it can be re-opened, to become an expert you have to stop making excuses. And I only down-voted after your rude response. So look, let's delete this pointless argument in the comments. I'll retract my down-vote. And if you improve your post, I'll vote to re-open.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @Tushar, It is almost certain that your input `a` or `b` contains NaN. Add an assert before the calculation, like `assert(isfinite(a[0])&&isfinite(a[1])&&isfinite(a[2]))`. I always do this to catch invalid numbers in my 3D routines.

Answer (score 2):

(Restricting this answer to IEEE754).

This is *only* possible if one of the terms is NaN, or some manifestation of undefined behaviour in your accessing outside the bounds of the array `a` or `b`, or reading uninitialised data.

Under IEEE754, you can't attain NaN by a multiplication of large values.

From C++11, you can use `std::isnan` to detect a NaN, prior to that or in C, use the idiom

```
if (f != f){
    // `f` is NaN
}
```

So, setting the undefined behaviour aside, the cause of the issue is higher up the call stack. Expressions such as 0.0 / 0.0 will generate a NaN.

---

Regarding your statement

> some value is divided by 0

the *only* value of "some value" that when divided by 0.0 gives you NaN is 0: `0.0 / 0.0` is NaN, and `a / 0.0` is +Inf if `a` is positive, and -Inf if `a` is negative.

Comment: @Bathseba, LOL  now I am getting nan's for values which were giving clear output earlier

Comment: You need to put some code in place that checks all the inputs. The actual cause will be higher up the call stack. (Something like 0.0 / 0.0 generates a NaN).

Comment: @Bathseba, Thanks man! It was a little logical error